# TFS 2018 Unauthorized when downloading current build artifact

Tags: tfs, tfs-2018

I'm trying to work with *TFS 2018 Artifacts*.

I created a very simple build (definition)- it has one agent phase that **uploading artifact**, and then another agent that should **download the artifact**.

The *Download Build Artifact* failed with *Unauthorized*:

```
Downloading artifacts from: {...}/tfs/DefaultCollection//_apis/resources/Containers/262302?itemPath=Artifact&isShallow=true&api-version=4.1-preview.4
Failed to parse response body: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</title>
.
.
.
```

(Also this message appears **five** times)

---

#### More details (please comment for asking to add more)

[image: Publish Artifact]

[image: Download Artifact]

Both phases marked with this:

[image: Allow OAuth]

[image: Failed step]

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Sorry, I'm on a vacation this week. Next week I will try your solution about the pool permissions

Answer (score 1):

> TFS 2018 Unauthorized when downloading current build artifact

According to the error message:

[image]

This is an authentication issue, you could check if those two Agent phases use the same build agent. And try to enable the option `Allow scripts to access OAuth token` in the `Agent phase` page:

[image]

If you are using different build agent, you should make sure your account has permission to access that agent:

`Agent Pools`-> `Agents`-> `Roles`

Add your account as `user` or `admin`.

If above not resolve this issue, I would like provide you a workaround to resolve it:

Create a share folder on your TFS server, then make sure your account could access that share folder, now we could publish our artifact to that share folder instead of `Visual Studio Team Services/TFS`：

[image]